# passing parameter to server in ExtJs

Tags: servlets, extjs

I am new in ExtJs.

I want to pass the value in my textbox to the server(Servlet) when I click on to the button. But as I am new to it I don't kn how to do it.

Please someone help me into this or suggest me some tutorial or example for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ext.Ajax.request](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/?class=Ext.Ajax) can help you.

Code will be look like this:

```
new Ext.Button({
    text: "Send to server",
    handler: function () {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'myPage.php',
            success: function (){alert('Value has been sent!');},
            failure: function (){alert('Failure of sending...');},
            headers: {
                'my-header': 'foo'
            },
            params: { foo: myTextField.getValue() }
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

in the url put your Servlet class name.
If you have a form with multiple buttons, for example Save, Update, Delete, you can to this :

```
// Your form fields ...
var buttonAdd = new Ext.Button({text:'Add', handler:addFunction});
var deleteAdd = new Ext.Button({text:'Delete', handler:deleteFunction});
function addFunction(){
    Ext.Ajax.Request({
        url: 'MyServlet', // you can fix a parameter like this : MyServlet?action=add
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
            myField1: myField1.getValue()
            // all your params.... 
        }
        success: function (result, request){
            alert('Succesfully added ' + result.responseText);
        },
        failure: function (result, request){
            alert('Error in server' + result.responseText);
        }
});

function deleteFunction(){
    Ext.Ajax.Request({
        url: 'MyServlet', // you can fix a parameter like this : MyServlet?action=delete
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
            myField1: myField1.getValue()
            // all your params.... 
        }
        success: function (result, request){
            alert('Succesfully added ' + result.responseText);
        },
        failure: function (result, request){
            alert('Error in server' + result.responseText);
        }
});
}
```

And in your Servlet, you can do this :

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    if(action.equals("add")){
        // Your code for add method goes here
    } else if(action.equals("delete")){
        // Your code for delete method goes here
    }
}
```