# iTextSharp generated PDF: How to send the pdf to the client and add a prompt?

Tags: c#, pdf, extjs, itext, prompt

I have generated a pdf using iTextSharp, when its created it saves automatically in the location provided in my code on the server not on the client side and of course without telling anything to the user.

I need to send it to the client and I need to prompt a dialogue box to ask the user where he wants to save his pdf..

how can i do this please?

this is my pdf code:

```
using (MemoryStream myMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter PDFWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, myMemoryStream);

    document.AddHeader("header1", "HEADER1");


    document.Open();

      //..........

    document.Close();

    byte[] content = myMemoryStream.ToArray();

    // Write out PDF from memory stream.
    using (FileStream fs =      File.Create(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\report.pdf")))
    {
        fs.Write(content, 0, (int)content.Length);
    }
```

**EDIT**

this is an example of the result i want
http://examples.extjs.eu/?ex=download

thanks to your replies ,I modified my code to this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf");


using (MemoryStream myMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{    
Document document = new Document();    
PdfWriter PDFWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, myMemoryStream);

document.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=wissalReport.pdf");

document.Open();

  //..........

document.Close();


byte[] content = myMemoryStream.ToArray();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = false;  
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();         
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent(); 
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();  
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename=" + "my_report.pdf");                
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";        

//Write the file content directly to the HTTP content output stream.    
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(content);         
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();                
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

but i get this error:

```
Uncaught Ext.Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: 
%PDF-1.4 %���� 3 0 obj <</Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width 994/Height 185/Length 13339/ColorSpace/DeviceGray/BitsPerComponent 8/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream x���|E�
...........
```

im absolutely sure my itextsharp to create pdf is correct because i can save it on the server, but thats not what i need to do ,when i try to send it to the client i got the error above

thanks in advance

Comment: is for WebApp/WinForm/Console program? You can always request a location before proceeding with pdf generation.

Comment: its a web application..how do do it? (sorry im new to c# and iTextSharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED

The error is from the submit operation trying to interpret the response which it can not because it is not in a known format.

I just set window.location to download files and this works fine.

```
{
xtype:'button',           
text: 'Generate PDF',           
handler: function () {
     window.location = '/AddData.ashx?action=pdf';                   
}
}
```

Instead of setting the location you can also do window.open().

Whether the file will be downloaded or opened depends on browser settings.

Comment: Third day I'm fighting with this problem!

I love you!

Answer (score 5):

In case of a web application you probably want to stream the pdf as binary to user, that would either open the pdf or prompt user to save the file.

Remember pdf generation is happening at server, even if user provides the path it won't be of any use on server. See following links -

- [How To Write Binary Files to the Browser Using ASP.NET and Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306654)

In your case you are generating the file and hence will already be having a binary stream instead of file, hence you can directly use [Response.BinaryWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.binarywrite.aspx) instead of [Response.WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.writefile.aspx).

Modified sample:

```
Response.Buffer = false;
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
//Set the appropriate ContentType.
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
//Write the file content directly to the HTTP content output stream.
Response.BinaryWrite(content);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: its fine i dont need it onserver i need the user to be able o save at his end..will look at this and let u know,ty

Comment: im not using Response.WriteFile! content u r referring to in ur sample is the same in my code byte[] content = myMemoryStream.ToArray(); ?

Comment: Yes - content is same as in your code. You need to use `Response.BinaryWrite(content)`.

Comment: It's going to stream the pdf created by PDF Writer. Make sure the `content` is correct (try saving it to a binary file) and try adding `Response.Flush()` before `Response.End()`

Comment: thats what i have used before but i had a problem,the pdf is not created,there is no prompt but i get error : Unexpected token %. and in fiddler i can see my pdf (i suppose to) in weird characters : %PDF-1.4 %���� 3 0 obj <>stream x��|E���r=�J Z M���XP_ `GDAQ���

Comment: I'm afraid that's a separate problem. The question you ask assumes you have been able to create a pdf (being able to save it on server atleast). And the problem (most probably) lies in your `//..........` code between `document.Open();` and `document.Close();`. Try to debug what's the issue is, give specific details in a new question and some one may be able help.

Comment: yes im able to create my pdf, the code in my question works perfectly fine..its when i replaced my using filestream... with ur code that i get the error described above :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5882/discussion-between-yetanotheruser-and-astrocybernaute)

Answer (score 3):

Currently you are saving your file on the file server, thereby overwriting the same pdf with every request. And probably causing errors if you get two requests for a PDF at the same time.

Use `Response` to return the PDF (from the memorystream) to the user, and skip the writing of the PDF to a file locally on your server.

The browser will ask the user where the file should be saved. Something like:

```
  Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
  myMemoryStream.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);
```

Also look at [the answer from Alun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8506382/11492), using `content-disposition` you can propose a filename to the user.

Comment: I see, iTextSharp will close the memorystream. Use the `Response.BinaryWrite(content)` from Yet's answer, and add a `Response.Clear()`.

Comment: thats what i have tried before but i had a problem,the pdf is not created,there is no prompt but i get error : Unexpected token %. and in fiddler i can see my pdf (i suppose to) in weird characters : %PDF-1.4 %���� 3 0 obj <>stream x��|E���r=�J Z M���XP_ `GDAQ���

Comment: Maybe your browser cached the content-type. Try pressing F5, or use another browser to test.

Answer (score 3):

You need to send a content disposition header to the users browser. From memory the code is something sort of like this:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=nameofthefile.pdf");
```

Comment: thx,tried it but it doesnt whow any prompt and it doesnt create my pdf..or at least i dont know where it did..

Comment: Are you sure this is a web app? Reading your code more closely it seems you are saving the pdf on the server rather than sending it to the client.

Comment: thats becaus ei dont know how to do it :(( ..but thats what i want to do..send the pdf to the client

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use `MemoryStream`. Use `Response.OutputStream` instead. That's what it's there for. No need to use `Response.BinaryWrite()` or any other call to explicitly write the document either; iTextSharp takes care of writing to the stream when you use `Response.OutputStream`.

Here's a simple working example:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader(
  "Content-Disposition",
  "attachment; filename=test.pdf"
);
using (Document document = new Document()) {
  PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
  document.Open();
  document.Add(new Paragraph("This is a paragraph"));
}
```

Here's [how to add the proper HTTP headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields). (getting the prompt to save the file) And if your code is in a `web form`, (button click handler), add `Response.End()` to the code example above after the `using` statement so that the web form's HTML output is not appended the PDF document.

Comment: thx..when tried it i had a problem,the pdf is not created,there is no prompt but i get error : Unexpected token %. and in fiddler i can see my pdf (i suppose to) in weird characters : %PDF-1.4 %���� 3 0 obj <>stream x��|E���r=�J Z M���XP_ `GDAQ���

Comment: "_Unexpected token %_" sounds like a JavaScript error - more so when you say you're using `fiddler`. How are you trying to send the PDF to the browser? Is this an Ajax app?

Comment: its an extjs app. how do i send pdf to browser? im not sure i nderstood..my code is in my question..

Comment: Your code to **generate** the PDF is in the question, but it looks like your **JavaScript** code is the problem. Never used extjs, maybe you need to do [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292788/passing-parameter-to-server-in-extjs)?

Comment: i already do this,i send parameter from my (exstjs) .js client and call the function to create my pdf which is a .cs. how could it be the problem? i already can generate my pdf its the prompt that i still need..

Comment: You should **retag** this question with extjs. Hopefully someone with experience with the library can help you. Couple of other options: [1] use a traditional ASP.NET web form, [2] move your code to an HTTP Handler (.ashx) and point a link/redirect to the .ashx URL.